# jquery css dock menu not working in ASP.NET masterpage

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm using css dock menu in my ASP.NET web app, I've used it in my master page but it doesn't work and I get a strange exception:

$('#dock').Fisheye is not a function

it is my document ready function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/interface.js"></script>
<link href="dock-menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


$(document).ready(function() {
    try
    {
        $('#dock').Fisheye(
                {
                    maxWidth: 50,
                    items: 'a',
                    itemsText: 'span',
                    container: '.dock-container',
                    itemWidth: 40,
                    proximity: 90,
                    halign: 'center'
                }
        )
    }
    catch (ex) {

    }

    $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
});
```

and this is my HTML containing the dock object:

```
<div class="dock" id="dock">
    <div class="dock-container">
        <a class="dock-item" href="/site/fa/DepartmentsNews.html" title="اخبار واحدهای سازمانی" alt="اخبار واحدهای سازمانی"><span>اخبار واحدهای سازمانی</span></a>                                               
        <a class="dock-item" href="/site/fa/ReportsCommunities.html" title="گزارش مجامع" alt="گزارش مجامع"><span>گزارش مجامع</span></a>                                               
        <a class="dock-item" href="/site/fa/FinancialReports.html" title="گزارشات مالی" alt="گزارشات مالی"><span>گزارشات مالی</span></a>                                               
    </div>
</div>
```

what is going wrong here?

Comment: have you referenced the script on your page for fisheye?

Comment: yes I've included js files containing this function, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean to say that there will be a script file which contains the definition of *fisheye* function. So did you reference that file before the code you have written above?

Comment: yes I've included this js file

Comment: can you show your jquery includes and the html for the menu?

Comment: I've added some code to my question

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `fisheye.js` file, you need to download that and include it. Just a guess but your js code is in the `interface.js` right? then the fisheye needs to be before that file.